# Google/Yahoo alternatives to geocoding?

Tags: api, geolocation, geocoding

Does anyone know of a good and accurate alternative web API for geocoding an address that is **not** Google or Yahoo?

I want to input an address/city/state/zip and have it return to me the latitude and longitude.

Ideally, I would involve it via a simple HTTP GET, e.g.

```
http://example.com/?location=123 Main St, New York, NY
```

and it would return JSON or XML with the latitude or longitude information.

Comment: just curious, can you share the reasons for not using Google/Yahoo (since they have the feature you asked about)?

Answer (score 1):

Geocoder.us is nice, and it is free (or cheap, depending on how you use it)

Answer (score 1):

[NAVTEQ Geocoder](http://www.nn4d.com/site/global/build/web_services/geocoding_reversegeocoding/map24geocoder51service/map24geocoder51service.jsp) can be your option.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to explorer mobile options too: http://developer.android.com

Answer (score 0):

Google has a very extensive list of alternatives, both free and fee for service:
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/NonGoogleGeocoders
(accessible as of 8/2015)
Texas A&M also has a list: https://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/Geocode/OtherGeocoders/
(also accessible as of 8/2015).
I provided links rather than cut and pasted the contents because the pages are more likely to be up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Check [**this**](http://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/Geocode/About/GeocoderList.aspx) for more Geocoding services.