# Google geocode API - free requests per day?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api, geocoding

I read here on Stack Overflow that standard Google API users are allowed up to 2,500 free requests per day:

[Geocoding API exceeds rate limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270363/geocoding-api-exceeds-rate-limit)

But I cannot seem to verify this anywhere. Does anyone know how many geocode requests you can make per day before Google will start charging?

Answer (score 3):

If you scroll down to the places section on this url https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet

This will tell you everything you need to know for your specifics.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks. But how many requests, roughly does the $200 credit equate to monthly?  Am I reading it right that it equates to 70,000 geocoding requests?  Should I take that to mean I get up to 70,000 geocoding requests monthly for free, and after that, I start paying?