# Why does Geocoder (1.38.1) output None?

Tags: python, geocoder

Why does the below piece of code give None as the output?

```
import geocoder
g = geocoder.google('Mountain View, CA')
print g.latlng
```

Answer (score 2):

To find the answer you can use the other code they provide for manually doing what geocoder does:

```
import requests
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json'
params = {'sensor': 'false', 'address': 'Mountain View, CA'}
r = requests.get(url, params=params)
results = r.json()
```

Looking in this object we can see that it contains an `error_message` key, as well as the status `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`. The error message reads as follows:

```
print(results['error_message'])
```

> You have exceeded your rate-limit for this API. We recommend
> registering for a key at the Google Developers Console:
> https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_

This is due to the fact that Google [stopped supporting keyless API access back on June 11, 2018](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/?_ga=2.124905161.212364110.1538961567-1131107758.1527643759). To use Google as the provider for geocoding you'll need to [get an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key) and enable billing. You may want to look at some [free alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217543/google-yahoo-alternatives-to-geocoding) for geocoding out there if you don't want to pay for their API access.

**EDIT:** Looks like the `geocoder` documentation also has [a list of alternatives](https://geocoder.readthedocs.io/#providers) that you can try using.

Comment: I'd suggest https://geocoder.readthedocs.io/providers/ArcGIS.html